# Characterization of right properness using slice categories

Tags: reference-request, model-categories

I would like to know how to cite this theorem (which has a quite surprising consequence):

> A model category $\mathcal{M}$ is right proper if and only if for any
>   weak equivalence $f:A\to B$, the Quillen adjunction
>   $\Sigma_f:\mathcal{M}/ A \leftrightarrows \mathcal{M} / B:f^*$ is a Quillen equivalence.

I had never heard of it (I never read that in any textbook I believe) before I browse the [nLab site](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proper+model+category) which refers to this [blog comment](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2012/05/the_mysterious_nature_of_right.html#c041294) from C. Rezk.

Comment: There is a general (and quite useful) lemma saying that a Quillen adjunction $L:\mathcal{M}\leftrightarrows\mathcal{N}:R$ in which $L$ preserves and detects weak equivalences is a Quillen equivalence if and only if the counit map $v: L(R(X)) \to X$ is a weak equivalence for every fibrant object $X \in \mathcal{N}$. Now observe that $\Sigma_f$ preserves and detects weak equivalences and that $\mathcal{M}$ is right proper exactly when for every weak equivalence $f: A \to B$ in $\mathcal{M}$ and every fibrant $X \in \mathcal{M}/B$ the counit map $v: \Sigma_f(f^*(X)) \to X$ is a weak equivalence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Proposition 2.7 in Rezk's [*Every Homotopy Theory of Simplicial Algebras Admits a Proper Model*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0003065v1)

Comment: Proposition 2.5 in the published version.

Comment: Thanks; I didn't have access to the published version, which is why I linked the arxiv version above.

Comment: It is freely available on the Web now (I mean legally freely available) : https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(01)00057-8